# Whay does it say "-bash: cd: hadoop: Not a directory"?

Tags: bash, hadoop, installation

I am trying to run "hadoop wordcount in python" by following [this](http://dogdogfish.com/hadoop/hadoop-wordcount-in-python/) tutorial. As in the tutorial, when I run this command `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -put ~/count_of_monte_cristo.txt /input`, it says `-bash: cd: hadoop: Not a directory`.

In tutorial it says that we need to put the text file by creating a a directory in HDFS. My question is if `/bin/hadoop` is not a accessible, where should I put the text file for analysis ? Are there any options ?  Or, Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Is `/usr/local/hadoop` a directory?

Comment: Can you show us the content of the path that you are using?

Comment: Te tutorial says: *cd /usr/local/hadoop ## If you followed the tutorial - otherwise, wherever your Hadoop home directory is*

Comment: My hadoop is here `/Users/JJ/hadoop-2.6.0` . So, I am not using the whole file path `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop` as shown in the tutorial because in my case bin is just inside hadoop-2.6.0(`>hadoop-2.6.0 > bin` ) so I am only using  `/bin/hadoop`.  Also, when I try to cd "hadoop" while I am in "/bin", it gives me the same error. Isn't "hadoop-2.6.0" my hadoop home directory ? If not,How do I know where my hadoop home directory is ?

Comment: `bin/hadoop` is an executable, not a folder, so you can't `cd` to it.

Comment: So, I am inside `hadoop-2.6.0` and it still gives me the same `/bin/hadoop: No such file or directory ` error when I run `/bin/hadoop fs -put ~/count_of_monte_cristo.txt /input` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Given you've installed Hadoop in `/Users/JJ/hadoop-2.6.0`, that is your home directory, and so you should be running

```
/Users/JJ/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop fs -put ~/count_of_monte_cristo.txt /input
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If `bin/hadoop` is not a folder how is it possible to put `count_of_monte_cristo.txt` in it ?

Comment: `bin/hadoop` is just the executable that lets you talk to the HDFS. It's not an actual folder on your machine. The HDFS is a distributed file system.

Answer (score 0):

/bin/hadoop or wherever your hadoop executable is located, you should be able to run hadoop filesystem commands using it. put command doesn't put the file in /bin/hadoop directory it tries to put file in location you specified, in your example in /input which is a directory expected in hdfs

When you run any hadoop fs command you are accessing hadoop distributed filesystem (Hdfs) if you have set that up. Else it will run on the local filesystem if you haven't setup Hdfs.

I would suggest first verify your hadoop executable is working fine by running. Replace hadoop with full path of executable if you haven't added hadoop in your PATH

`hadoop fs -ls`

If it returns directories in hdfs you are good. Else you might not have setup cluster correctly